# Faster algo v/s faster computer

Tags: algorithm, performance

Please help me in understanding these question (solution below):
(a) Suppose that another algorithm has time complexity T(n) = n^2, and that executing an implementation of it on a particular machine takes T seconds for n inputs. Now suppose that we are presented with a machine that is 64 times faster. How many inputs would we process on the new machine in T seconds?

(b) Suppose that a particular algorithm has time complexity T(n) = 3 * 2^n, and executing an implementation of it on a particular machine takes T seconds for n inputs. Now suppose that we are presented with a machine that is 64 times faster. How many inputs would we process on the new machine in T seconds?

Solution found online for (a):
If the slower computer does S computations (cycles) in time T, then the faster computer does 64S calculations (cycles).

Assume that the slower computer can solve a problem size of (at most) ​n​ in time ​T.
This means it makes about n2 =S computations.

How much bigger size than n can run in 64S, given that the growth rate of the algorithm on input size n is T(n)=n2?

If  n2 ≈ S, then T(64n) = 64n2 ≈ 64S
Please explain the solution if possible.

Thanks

Comment: 8 times n would take 8*8 as long, so a 64x machine can do 8xn. Substitute a constant times `n` into the equation and then solve it to find the constant.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/122078/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3591635/14578, https://stackoverflow.com/q/60804010/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This more mathematics than programming:

(a) Here you will gain x times more (x * n).

```
64 * n^2 = (x * n)^2 = x^2 * n^2    | /n^2
64 = x^2                            | sqrt
x = 8
```

(b) Here, because it is exponential, n can just be x greater (n + x).

```
64 * 3 * 2^n = 3 * 2^(x + n)        | /3
64 * 2^n = 2^n * 2^x                | /2^n
64 = 2^x                            | log2
x = 6
```

Comment: If running time is constant such as 20n then follow same steps as (a) i.e. we will gain x times more AND  what about linear log running time ?

Comment: @FNF yes if running time is polynomial (this includes linear) you will get x times more. If the running time is logarithmic you will gain n^x more: 64 log(n) = log(n^x) => x = 64

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again what about linear log e.g. T(n) = 5nlogn

Comment: @FNF The 5 doesn't matter. You cannot express the gain for nlogn independent of n (or it is very complicated). Its all about the reverse functions: the reverse for power is log and log(xn) = log(x) + log(n), the reverse funtion of squared is the square root and sqrt(xn) = sqrt(x) * sqrt(n), so it is a factor. The reverse function for n log n is very complicated (lambert w function, I dont really understand it).